# Python CSV: Lines Not Displaying

Tags: python, csv

I'm using Python 3.6.

I have a list of tuples, where the first element in the tuple is an ID and the second is a prediction (0 or 1).  I want to create a CSV with a header of `"PassengerId, Survived"` and a sample row might be `"237, 1"`.

Here's my attempt:

```
import csv
with open("Predictions.csv", "wb") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["PassengerId", "Survived"])
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow([row[0], row[1]])
```

Unfortunately, the file has the header but none of the rows I've attempted to write to the CSV.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: in your for loop where are `rows` defined?

Comment: @MikeTung Problem solved :)